# calling function with 2 parameters onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function from a dynamically created element which contains 2 parameters, but it is sending it as only only parameter by merging the two.

```js
$("#click").click(function(){
  var td = document.createElement('div');
  var num1 = 10;
  var num = 5;
  td.innerHTML = "new";
  $(td).attr('onclick','updateDistance("'+num1+','+num+'")');
  document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(td);
})

function updateDistance(id,distance){
  alert(id+","+distance);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "div1">
  Text here
</div>
<button id = "click">CLick here</button>
```

please help

Comment: @Kinduser please run the code first :)

Comment: Why are you mixing inline javascript event listeners with unobtrusive ones? Use jQuery or native methods...don't mix them

Comment: @charlietfl how does it matter?

Comment: Makes for a non uniform inconsistent code base. That typically is harder to maintain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because your

```
$(td).attr('onclick','updateDistance("'+num1+','+num+'")');
```

Is creating a script like this

```
updateDistance("10,5")
```

Is just a string with a comma in the middle. One parameter. You want to create this:

```
updateDistance("10","5")
```

So for this you have to do it this way:

```
$(td).attr('onclick','updateDistance("'+num1+'","'+num+'")');
```

Notice where I added the quotes.

By the way, being numbers, you can avoid the quotes:

```
$(td).attr('onclick','updateDistance('+num1+','+num+')');
```

And this will create this:

```
updateDistance(10,5)
```

So they are passed as numbers, not strings. There's a big difference between `"10"` and `10` (without quotes).

Also, you can attach a click event that will call the function directly, without any hack:

```
$(td).on('click', function() { updateDistance(num1, num); });
```

And if you are creating a lot of elements and having problems with the variables values outside the click context, check this answer I recently written: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42283571/1525495

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call it inside a function:

Change

```
$(td).attr('onclick','updateDistance("'+num1+','+num+'")');
```

To this:

```
$(td).click(function() {
    updateDistance(num1,num);
});
```

If your two parameters are dynamic, you can have them assigned to the object `td` and reused.

```
$("#click").click(function(){
  var td = document.createElement('div');
  td.id = 10; // or however you calculate this value
  td.distance = 5; // or however you calculate it.
  td.innerHTML = "new";
  $(td).click(function() {
      // extract the dynamic value and call the function with it.
      var id = this.id;
      var distance = $(this).prop("distance");
      updateDistance(id,distance);
  });
  document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(td);
});
```

### Here is a working example:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jdqp6x1a/)

Comment: that won't help because there are hundreds of such elements