# Twitch TV API JSON Issue

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitch

I work with Twitch API. If the streamer streams I work with with property "Stream". But If he's not streaming, then I need refer to another link. Then I again turn to the function of the getJSON and pass there the necessary API link. And I'm working with her. However, the loop does not work as it should. It takes the last streamer out of the "channels" array, but it should all those who do not stream. I can not understand what the problem is. Help...

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e7gLL25y/

```
JS Code:

var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

var channels = ["summit1g", "esl_RuHub_CSGO", "Starladder1", "Senpai_Frozen", "tehvivalazz", "ESL_CSGO"];
var client_id = "hx3dea4ifwensxffoe8iwvekwvksnx";
var section = document.getElementById("main-section");

var streamer = [];
for(var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {

    var url_channels = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + channels[i] + "?client_id=" + client_id;
    var url_streams = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channels[i] + "?client_id=" + client_id;

    getJSON(url_streams, function(response) {
        if( response["stream"] !== null ) {
            streamer[i] = document.createElement("div");
            streamer[i].className = "streamer";
            streamer[i].innerHTML = "<a target='_blank' href='" + response.stream.channel["url"] + 
                                        "'><img id='streamer-image' src='" + 
                                        response.stream.channel["logo"] + 
                                        "' alt='Av' /><h2 id='streamer-name'>" + 
                                        response.stream.channel["name"] + 
                                        "</h2><p id='stream-status'>" + 
                                        response.stream["game"] + "</p></a>";
            section.appendChild(streamer[i]);
        } else {
            getJSON(url_channels, function(r) {
                streamer[i] = document.createElement("div");
                streamer[i].className = "streamer";
                streamer[i].innerHTML = "<a target='_blank' href='" + r["url"] + 
                                            "'><img id='streamer-image' src='" + 
                                            r["logo"] + 
                                            "' alt='Av' /><h2 id='streamer-name'>" + 
                                            r["name"] + 
                                            "</h2><p id='stream-status'>Offline</p></a>";
                section.appendChild(streamer[i]);
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a common misconception about JavaScript contexts.

Refer to my answer here to see details about this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42283571/1525495

Simply, the `getJSON` response is called after all the array is looped, so `i` will be the last index in all the responses. You have to create another context to keep the `i` number so is not increased.

```
for(var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {

    var url_channels = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + channels[i] + "?client_id=" + client_id;
    var url_streams = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channels[i] + "?client_id=" + client_id;
    (function(i) {
        // i will not be changed by the external loop as is in another context
        getJSON(url_streams, function(response) {
            // Thingy things...
        });
    })(i);

}
```